# Creating 2 columns inside 6 columns with flex and aligning two items

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I want to design a card using a 12-column system with flex
In this card, text and photo are together, and I don't know if I should consider 2 columns of six or not, and no matter what I try, I can't achieve the desired shape. What changes should I make to get something like this picture?

[image]

```css
.card {
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: #ffece1;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card__content {
  display: flex;
}

.card h1 {
  font-family: var(--font-secondary);
  font-size: calc(var(--spacing) * 15);
  line-height: calc(var(--spacing) * 18);
}
.row {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 margin-left: -8px;
 margin-right: -8px;
}

.col {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding-left: 8px;
 padding-right: 8px;
}

.col-6 {
 width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-6">
        <div class="card">
          <h1>Mediterranean Cobb Salad</h1>
          <p>Serves: 2 people</p>

          <div class="card__content">
            <p>American garden salad typically made with chopped salad greens, tomato, crisp bacon, hard-boiled
              eggs,
              avocado, chives, blue cheese, and red-wine vinaigrette
            </p>
            <img src="/img/fresh-salad-with-turkey-eggs-vegetables-removebg-preview.png" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
```

Comment: why don't you use the css grid layout it is perfect to design your type of card. Here it seems you are using Bootstrap styling which is not adequate for what you want to do apparently

Comment: You are have a design which needs 2 dimensions so as @Mehdi suggests, flex is not adequate. CSS grid with 12 columns as you sr suggest is probably accurate enough for your design with perhaps the main text taking 7 columns and the image 5 rather than half and half. Have a go at coding using grid and if still stuck post your new code in the question so we can help.